# Porque me ocurre este error: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy realizando un buscador SQL con php y estoy realizando para que se muestren en la pestaña search.php pero me salta el siguiente error que no entiendo como solucionarlo.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","animezco") or die ("DB Error");
$output = '';
//collect

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = str_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
    
    $query = mysqli_query($link ,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("Query Error");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($count == 0){
        $output = 'No se han encontrado resultados!';
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $tname = $row['title'];
            
            $output .= '<div class="title">'.$tname.'</div>';
        }
    }
}

?>

     <div class="search">
        
          <button onclick="show_hide()" class="searchButton">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
         <form action="search.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" id="input" name="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Buscar anime..."/>

           </form>

    </div>
```

Codigo: search.php

```
<div class="blog-add">
    <a href="#">

    <p class="blog-title"><?php echo $row['title']?></p>
        </a>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor alguien me puede ayudar con este error que no entiendo como solucionarlo.

Comment: Saludos. El mensaje te indica que solicitas un elemento de un array de una variable cuyo valor es `null`; verifica que `$row` al momento de usarla tiene asignado un valor de tipo array y existe la posición `'title'`.

Comment: ¿El primer bloque de código está en un archivo distinto de `search.php`? Si es así, ¿por qué usas `$row` en `search.php` si no tendrías esa variable en contexto?